# Escape newline in source

Tags: dokuwiki, wiki-markup

There's a huge wiki page in our dokuwiki I have the pleasure of having to edit, the problem is that most of it is a giant table.

I know you can [insert a newline](https://serverfault.com/questions/128924/creating-tables-in-dokuwiki) into the result without writing a newline in the markup (which would be interpreted as a [paragraph change](https://www.dokuwiki.org/wiki:syntax#basic_text_formatting)), but all I want to do is put line breaks in the source and not have it affect the wiki page at all (so it's easier for editors to read, like an html table I suppose, where literal newlines are ignored).

So is there some syntax available to escape a newline in dokuwiki, not unlike `\` for bash or `^` for DOS?

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is *afaik* not possible in the dokuwiki core.

One alternative would be the [edittable](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:edittable)-plugin. It lets you edit your table within an actual table-editor. However the current version is somewhat flaky in very wide tables. Should that be an issue for you, then you could try an [older version from June 2015](https://github.com/cosmocode/edittable/releases/tag/2015-06-17).